# Python SQLite Update Function not working

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using Python 3.7.5 and SQLite3 3.X as well as Tkinter (but that's irrelevant) and I can't seem to update my table called "Account"

```
try:
    Cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE Account (
        Application text,
        Username text,
        Password text)""")
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    Cursor.execute("""UPDATE Account SET
        Application = :NewApp,
        Username = :NewUser,
        Password = :NewPass
        WHERE oid = :oid""",
        {"NewApp": NewApplicationE.get(),
         "NewUser": NewUsernameE.get(),
         "NewPass": NewPasswordE.get(),
         "oid": X[3]
        })
```

The try bit is just to create the table if there's not already one and if there is it goes on to update the table
I know for a fact there's columns called Application, Username, Password and the variable.get() all returns the proper string 
The oid being X[3] gives you an integer

The program runs but it doesn't actually seem to update anything.
Any help with the formatting or just in general would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need just commit your change
I assume that you get cursor from a connectio,
For instance something like that should work:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')c = conn.cursor()
Cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    Cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE Account (
        Application text,
        Username text,
        Password text)""")
     conn.commit()

except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    Cursor.execute("""UPDATE Account SET
        Application = :NewApp,
        Username = :NewUser,
        Password = :NewPass
        WHERE oid = :oid""",
        {"NewApp": NewApplicationE.get(),
         "NewUser": NewUsernameE.get(),
         "NewPass": NewPasswordE.get(),
         "oid": X[3]
        })
        conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

**Referece**
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html